# External access with SSH

Tags: ssh

I need to remotely access my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Trusty server.
SSH is already installed.
My question is what address should I use for access from outside the network where the server is

Comment: You have to set up port forwarding on your router.

Comment: Give me the model of the router and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Modem Router WiFi D-Link 2740.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a static ip adress you should enable **dynamic DNS** (for example with [freedns.afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org)). And you have to enable Port **forwarding of Port 22** (or something else if you changed the port).

Than use the Dynamic DNS adress to connect with your server.

*P.s. When using a FritzBox you can (and should) use AVM's MyFritz service as Dynamic DNS*

Comment: My ip really is not static.
I think I should use a dyndns address.
You would redirect some of this script as an example?
I did not understand anything about FritBox or AVMMyfritz? Could you explain me better?

Comment: @FelipeValim the FritzBox is just a router,so if you don't know what it is you simply use another router and you can ignore the last sentence

Comment: You don't need any scripts. Tutees can do this by themself. Just Google for 'dyn DNS with <router model >